# Trying to add items in list of lists of tuples

Tags: python, django

I am making a game picking app and I am stuck on trying to get a summary of points for users.
The list is consisting of 18 lists (weeks) with all users and their respective points, sorted alphabetically. I don't know how to create a list with user---> all points combined.

Here is an example with only 2 users

```
[[('user1', 25), ('user2 ', 18)], [('user1', 18), ('user2 ', 25)], [('user1', 18), ('user2 ', 25)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)]]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output would be a list, or dict with user and his points combined for all weeks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried looping through somehow but i always get stuck with recognizing 'user1' and adding his points to him

Comment: In the future, try to include as much info as possible in your question - especially code you wrote so far, expected and actual output - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Since you are using Django, it looks like simply storing it in a good way in the database should be sufficient for this.

Answer (score 1):

That's what I'd suggest:

```
from collections import Counter

data = [[('user1', 25), ('user2 ', 18)], [('user1', 18), ('user2 ', 25)], [('user1', 18), ('user2 ', 25)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)]]

user_points = Counter()
for week in data:
    for user, points in week:
        user_points[user] += points

print(user_points) # Counter({'user2 ': 68, 'user1': 61})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `zip` and dict comprehensions

```
lst = [[('user1', 25), ('user2 ', 18)], [('user1', 18), ('user2 ', 25)], [('user1', 18), ('user2 ', 25)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)], [('user1', 0), ('user2 ', 0)]]
d = {x[0][0]: sum(list(zip(*x))[1]) for x in zip(*lst)}
print(d) # {'user1': 61, 'user2 ': 68}
```

Comment: d = {x[0][0]: sum(list(zip(*x))[1]) for x in zip(*lst)}
NameError: name 'lst' is not defined. Did you mean: 'list'?

Comment: @toyotaSupra `lst` is the list of the users

Comment: Sorry, I left out lst. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work:

```
data = your_list
out = {}

for week in data:
    for user in week:
        if user[0] in out.keys():
            out[user[0]] += user[1]
        else:
            out[user[0]] = user[1]

print(out) # Just in case you want to try
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).